# How is a corelation of function inputs to its outputs is called in math?

Tags: confidence-interval

So I  have a function $f$ and for a set of argument intervals I have a set of its result intervals?

Example: say for $f(x)$ I have $f(2..6) = -1..2$ and $-inf..+inf$ for all others (ones I do not care about or do not have info).

How calculation and operatoion on such intervals is called?

Comment: And it is not related to `confidence-interval`  because there are no probabiletoies involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)).

I don't know if operations on images hava a special name, though; they are just sets to be transformed or whatever.